# Incoming emails of specific domain not working

Tags: domain-name-system, email, smtp

The domain of my website as an example is www.abc.cc. The IP of it is 1.1.1.1 as an example also. And, the IP of mail is different. It is as an example 2.2.2.2 and the problem is i can send an email through any email under this domain but I can not receive any email. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: More information is required, in particular: - What environment is your server running on?
- in terms of testing, what have you tried?
- Have you set up spf and/or dkim records?
- Have you consulted any message tracking logs?
- Do you have any security in place (firewalls etc.) that could stop incoming messages?

Comment: in term of testing: i only send a massge and then i get this massage: Delivery incomplete
There was a temporary problem delivering your message to a@abc.cc. Gmail will retry for 47 more hours. You'll be notified if the delivery fails permanently.   The response was:
The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect. [abc.cc. 1.1.1.1: timed out] Final-Recipient: rfc822; a@abc.cc
Action: delayed
Status: 4.4.1
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect

Comment: Can you enter your actual domain name? If not, can you use MX Toolbox and reply with your output? https://mxtoolbox.com

Comment: What environment is your server running on? i don't know . it's not my server . Have you set up spf and/or dkim records? i change CNAME record  of mail.abc.cc to  A record as 2.2.2.2 and not working

Comment: What are your MX records set at? Can you use the tool I mentioned and reply with output? You need more than just a CNAME and A record.

Comment: 0 mx record and smtp test for 1.1.1.1 is : SMTP Reverse DNS Resolution: Reverse DNS Resolution - No PTR Record found  
 SMTP TLS: Warning - Does not support TLS.  
 SMTP Server Disconnected: May be an open relay.

Comment: smtp test for 2.2.2.2 is: SMTP Banner Check: Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner SMTP TLS Warning - Does not support TLS.  
 SMTP Transaction Time 15.064 seconds - Not good! on Transaction Time 
 SMTP Reverse DNS Mismatch OK - 2.2.2.2 resolves to rs104.nsresponse.com 
 SMTP Valid Hostname OK - Reverse DNS is a valid Hostname 
 SMTP Connection Time 0 seconds - Good on Connection time 
 SMTP Open Relay OK - Not an open relay.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't have an MX records set (unless of course I missed that)? It is possible to fallback to A records (see https://serverfault.com/a/470651/435758) but it's always best practice to have an MX records present.

Comment: I get mx record from cmd by this command nslookup -debug -q=mx abc.cc. MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = mx1.norelay.stc.com.sa ttl = 0 (0 secs)

Comment: Provide true names and IPs if you want people to help you.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/340759)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but this error usually  come from two possible source.

- Your MX is not set correctly. The public DNS MX should point to 2.2.2.2. To test please use nslookup, set q=mx, domain.com, it should list your mx
- Your router doesn't forward the port 25 to your server. (Incoming NAT rule in your router, 2.2.2.2 ==> ip of your server on port 25) To test try from home to telnet to your server, telnet public_ip 25, you should see the email server prompt.

Edit: After our comment, please put 2.2.2.2 as your MX, the host you currently have there is not valid

Comment: I get mx record from cmd by this command nslookup -debug -q=mx abc.cc. MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = mx1.norelay.stc.com.sa ttl = 0 (0 secs)

Comment: @Amd2030 a normal nslookup mx1.norelay.stc.com.sa = 2.2.2,2 ?

Comment: i don't understand your question

Comment: @Amd2030 If you ping that host, it return 2.2.2.2 ?

Comment: no ip return. return this: MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = mx1.norelay.stc.com.sa ttl = 0 (0 secs)

Comment: try ping nx1.norelay.stc.com.sa, what return?

Comment: Ping request could not find host mx1.norelay.stc.com.sa. Please check the name and try again.

Comment: @Amd2030 your error is there, it must ne 2.2,2,2 there, as the receiving email is sent to that address, that currently resolve to nothing, editing my answer to reflect that new info

Comment: i put 2.2.2.2 as mx record but it's not working

Comment: @Amd2030 the true ip, not actually 2.2.2.2?

Comment: yes of course i put true ip

Comment: @Amd2030 perfect, your router forward the port 25 to your mail server? to know if the firewall block it you can try a telnet 2.2.2.2 25, it should answer

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved by the following steps:

1. edit MX record from abc.cc to mail.abc.cc
2. add A record of mail.abc.cc to IP 2.2.2.2
3. remove dmarc and disabled Dkim and SPF
4. edit email routing to local mail exchanger